# How can I check an element for multiple CSS classes in Cypress?

Tags: testing, e2e-testing, cypress

How to check if an element has multiple classes?
Couldn't find anything on the official docs, only:

`cy.get('form').find('input').should('have.class', 'disabled')`

or

`expect($el).to.have.class('foo')`

When inserting multiple class names, I get an error:

`expect($el).to.have.class('foo bar baz')`

Is there a solution?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

One way is to chain multiple assertions together using [`cy.and()`](https://on.cypress.io/and):

```js
cy.get('div')
.should('have.class', 'foo')
.and('have.class', 'bar')
.and('have.class', 'baz')
```

Comment: Thanks. Although I expected something like passing multiple class strings in a sinle assertion, but I guess that's the way to go.

Comment: Well, if you have an element like `<div class="a b c"/>`, `cy.get('div').should('have.class', 'a b c')` will actually pass - but ONLY if the `class` attribute is exactly "a b c". So it's not a good idea to rely on this.

Comment: Oh, in my case it wasn't `a b c`, so that's why it failed!

Answer (score 0):

One can certainly use a little helper function `BUT` it only makes sense with longer class lists as it adds two more lines to your test code.

Helper function:

```js
function shouldHaveClasses(el, classList = []) {
  classList.forEach((c) => {
    expect(el).to.have.class(c)
  })
}
```

Your test:

```js
describe('My Test', () => {
  cy.get('div')
    .then((el) => {
      shouldHaveClasses(el, ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'])
    })
})
```

Comment: Looks like you missed a parameter in the example.

Comment: @TesterDick You're right, thanks for pointing it out for me. It's corrected now.